# Github Actions: No such file or directory when running app deployment script

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions

On my vps, my app structure is such:

```
root
├── app
    ├── .github/workflows
        ├── deploy.yml
    ├── docker-compose.prod.yml
    ├── redeploy-site.sh
```

I have a deploy.yml set up for whenever I push to github. This is supposed to run my redeploy-site.sh script, which should mean my site gets redeployed everytime I push. Here's my deploy.yml file:

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: "Deploy to VPS"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Configure SSH
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh/
          echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/deploy-key.pem
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/deploy-key.pem
          cat >> ~/.ssh/config <<END
          Host my-vps
            HostName $SSH_IP
            User $SSH_USER
            IdentityFile ~/.ssh/deploy-key.pem
            StrictHostKeyChecking no
          END
        env:
          SSH_USER: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          SSH_IP: ${{ secrets.SSH_IP }}

      - name: Give Permissions to redeploy-site.sh
        run: ssh my-vps 'chmod +x ~/app/redeploy-site.sh'

      - name: Deploy my site!
        run: ssh my-vps '~/app/redeploy-site.sh'
```

here is my redeploy-site.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "navigating to project directory"

cd ~/app/

echo "Navigated to project directory."
echo "---------------------------------------------"

echo "running git fetch"

git fetch && git reset origin/main --hard

echo "Ran git fetch."
echo "---------------------------------------------"

echo "running docker compose down"

docker compose -f ~/app/docker-compose.prod.yml down

echo "ran docker compose down"
echo "---------------------------------------------"

echo "running docker compose up"

docker compose -f ~/app/docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --build

echo "ran docker compose up"
echo "---------------------------------------------"
```

However, this is the output I get for the "Deploy my site!" step on github actions:

```
Run ssh my-vps '~/app/redeploy-site.sh'
  ssh my-vps '~/app/redeploy-site.sh'
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
running git fetch
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Ran git fetch.
---------------------------------------------
running docker compose down
stat /***/docker-compose.prod.yml: no such file or directory
ran docker compose down
---------------------------------------------
running docker compose up
stat /***/docker-compose.prod.yml: no such file or directory
ran docker compose up
---------------------------------------------
```

What I instantly notice is that `/***/docker-compose.prod.yml` (where *** is just the ssh user, which, in this case, is just 'root') is the wrong filepath. It should be `/***/app/docker-compose.yml`

My question is twofold. First, why is the log completely skipping over the part where I first navigate to the app directory? It's not even printing out the echo statements associated with that block in redeploy-site.sh. I did have this part commented out before, but it's not anymore and my github repo shows it as such. Second, and more importantly, how do I resolve the "no such file or directory" error, when the docker compose file is clearly there?

(I've also tried pushing this script without the first step of cd'ing into the app, and without the absolute path to the docker-compose.prod.yml file)

Comment: You workflow does not contain a step, to push the local repository changes to the remote machine. Instead "Deploy my site!" step is executing the script, that is already on the machine. Have you verified that the script on the remote machine matches with the script your shared with us?